# Ingreso Empleado JavaScript, no logro resolverlo?

Tags: javascript

EJERCICIO 10  ingresoEmpleado

> Implementar la función ingresoEmpleado que servirá para registrar el ingreso de los empleados apuntando aquellos que hayan llegado a horario.
> IMPORTANTE! Los horarios serán números enteros (9,10,11,12), NO tendrán formato hora (09:00, 10:00)
> La función ingresoEmpleado debe retornar la función ingresosHorario, la cual recibirá un arreglo de empleados que ingresan al supermercado con la siguiente forma:

```
let empleados =  [
   {nombre:"Jorge", ingresoA: 9},
   {nombre:"Mora", ingresoA: 8},
   {nombre:"Mati", ingresoA: 10},
   {nombre:"Juani", ingresoA: 7}
 ]
```

> y retornará un nuevo arreglo con LOS NOMBRES de aquellos que se hayan presentado antes del horario de ingreso.

Ejemplo

```
const ingresosHorario =  ingresoEmpleado(9)
```

Si ejecuto ingresosHorario(empleados) me daria de resultado `["Jorge"]`

```
function ingresoEmpleado(horario) {
// Tu código aquí:
  let array=[];
return function ingresosHorario(empleados){
let nombre=prop;
for( prop in empleados){
  while(empleados.length>0){
    if(empleados[nombre])
  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) { 
    if(empleados[nombre][i][0]<horario){   
     
     ingresosHorario(array.push(empleados[i][""]));
   }}}
  };
 return array}
}
```

He intentado el código de arriba, además de varios ajustes, pero nada da resultado, ya no sé qué hacer, no tengo prisa por resolverlo, sino por entenderlo, si me lo pueden explicar además de resolverlo muchísimo mejor, gracias.

las cosas que he intentado son únicamente cambiar las variables de lugar e intentar que no me tire errores, no soy un experto, estoy aprendiendo y no sé como seguir, si pueden tirarme algún tip o alguna referencia de investigación con gusto busco, desde ya, gracias por su tiempo.

Me aparece ésto al ejecutar el test:
[image: imagen de lo que me aparece en consola al ejecutar el test]

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: En vez de poner spam, podríás explicar en detalle qué es "nada da resultado". Qué errores hay, en detalle. Cuáles son los ajustes que ya intentaste, como código, como texto. Considera [edit] la pregunta y quitar el spam para poner la info relevante que falta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y el problema de ese codigo cual es?

Comment: Disculpa, lo eh editado, gracias por tu comentario pero ya no sé que hacer, cambié variables, busqué y busqué pero hay algo que no veo, si lo ves me ayudaría muchísimo

Comment: el problema del código que yo escribí es que se corta cuando retorna la primer funcion, me retorna ingresoHorario(empleados) pero no me retorna el resultado, o sea un array con el nombre de la persona que llegó antes de la hora

Comment: El enunciado del problema me genera muchas dudas, no lo pillo bien, diría que está mal expuesto en sí. Aún así, tienes un par de cosas que sí puedes arreglar, como esto: `for( prop in empleados){` cambiarlo por esto: `for( prop of empleados){`, y luego el `let nombre=prop;` debe ir dentro del bucle, sino **prop** no vale nada.

Comment: Pon _en la pregunta_ (no como comentario) el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. No pidas orientaciones: pon cuál es el problema en sí. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

- La función `ingresosHorario` no debe ejecutarse a sí misma (recursiva)
- Con `let nombre=prop;` estás tratando de acceder a una variable que defines en la siguiente línea `for( prop in empleados)` y, por supuesto, te va a generar error
- En lugar de un ciclo `for`, te recomiendo el método [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) porque creo que es más sencillo, aunque es cuestión de preferencias
- Dentro del ciclo tienes otros más y, al menos la condición del `while` parece que no se va a cumplir, por lo que será un ciclo infinito

Al recorrer con `forEach`, en cada iteración vas a obtener un elemento del arreglo y puedes acceder a sus propiedades, por ejemplo:

- `empleado.nombre`
- `empleado.ingresoA` - Esta es la que se va a usar para comparar el horario

> Retornará un nuevo arreglo con LOS NOMBRES de aquellos que se hayan presentado **antes del horario de ingreso**.

Toma nota del texto en negrillas.

> Si ejecuto `ingresosHorario(empleados)` me daría de resultado `["Jorge"]`

Si ejecutas `ingresosHorario(empleados);` te debe devolver los empleados que ingresaron **antes de la hora** especificada en la primera función.

```js
let empleados =  [
   { nombre: "Jorge", ingresoA: 9 },
   { nombre: "Mora", ingresoA: 8 },
   { nombre: "Mati", ingresoA: 10 },
   { nombre: "Juani", ingresoA: 7 }
];

function ingresoEmpleado(horario) {
    return function ingresosHorario(empleados) {
        // Crear arreglo vacío
        let arr = [];
        // Recorrer empleados
        empleados.forEach(empleado => {
            // ¿Entró antes del horario?
            if(empleado.ingresoA < horario) {
                // Se cumplió la condición, agregar al arreglo
                arr.push(empleado.nombre);
            }
        });
        // Devolver los empleados que entraron antes del horario especificado
        return arr;
    }
}

const ingresosHorario = ingresoEmpleado(9);
console.log(ingresosHorario(empleados));
```

Comment: FUNCIONÓ, muchas gracias por tu comentario, me ayudaste muchísimo, no conozco forEach pero voy a investigar muchas gracias de verdad